# Spectrum of the product of positive elements of a $C^\ast$-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

I am working on problem 2.a in Murphy's $\textit{$C^\ast$-Algebras and Operator Theory}$, which asks to show that for positive elements $a, b$ of a unital $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, $\sigma(ab) \subset [0, \infty)$. By the definition given in this textbook, $a \in A$ is positive if $a$ is hermitian and $\sigma(a) \subset [0, \infty)$.

It's true that, if $a$ and $b$ commute, then $ab$ is positive, as:
$$ab = (a^{1/2}b^{1/2})^\ast (a^{1/2}b^{1/2}),$$
from which it follows that $\sigma(ab) \subset [0, \infty)$.

Then, to solve the given problem, I invoke the following argument:
$$\sigma(ab) \cup \{0\} = \sigma((a^{1/2}b^{1/2})^\ast (a^{1/2}b^{1/2})) \cup \{0\} \subset [0, \infty),$$

from which it follows that $\sigma(ab) \subset [0, \infty)$.

My question is this: we have that, for arbitrary positive $a, b \in A$, $a$ and $b$ are hermitian, from which it follows that $ab$ is hermitian. Furthermore, by the above argument, it follows that $\sigma(ab) \subset [0, \infty)$. Does it not follow from this that $ab$ is positive for arbitrary positive $a,b$?

Comment: The solution to this problem can be found here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168470/if-a-ge-0-and-b-ge-0-then-sigmaab-subset-mathbbr?rq=1

Although, to answer your question, the product of non-commuting positive elements will in general not be positive. It is not even self-adjoint in general (you can show this for 2x2 matrices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that the product of hermitian operators is hermitian in general. For instance try 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\2&3\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\4&6\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Actually, for $a,b$ hermitian we have that $ab$ is hermitian if and only if $ab=ba$.